# Excel Error 424 Help Needed

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out why Excel doesn't like this code and I've stepped through all of my (albeit) limited knowledge on how to troubleshoot it.

My code calls a ProperUnion code I found online which is supposed to handle null ranges and duplicates. I have only a basic grasp of how the second bit of code works. The first bit is all mine.

This code selects a list of items based on whether they are flagged, saves each flag as a range, and then intersects them as necessary. In the case I am testing only the "Flag 3" box is checked which might be what is causing the issue. (So rngx(1) rngx(2) rngx(4) + are all null values.)

I put 'xxxxxxx on the line in Proper union that is giving me the debug error.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Gather Flagged Information Code

```
Sub GSFlagged(prg As String) 'prg is the Program Name
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngx(1 To 8) As Variant
Dim rngu As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wsGenScore As Worksheet
Dim wsScore As Worksheet

Set wsMaster = Worksheets("Master List")
Set wsGenScore = Worksheets("Generate Scorecard")
Set wsScore = Worksheets("Scorecard")

wsMaster.Activate
'Make sure that the master list is not filtered
    If wsMaster.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    wsMaster.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

'Select all data in the Masterlist and then remove the headers
Set rng = wsMaster.Range("B4:E4", Range("B4:E4").End(xlDown))
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)

'Filter by the program name
    wsMaster.Range("B4").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=prg
    Set rngA = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Filter by flags with a loop over the variable r and save each set of visible cells as rngx(r)
    For r = 1 To 8
        If wsGenScore.Shapes("Flag" & r).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
            wsMaster.Activate
            If wsMaster.AutoFilterMode = True Then
                wsMaster.AutoFilterMode = False
            End If
        wsMaster.Range("B4").AutoFilter Field:=r + 6, Criteria1:="<>"
        Set rngx(r) = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End If
    Next r
'After filtering through all the SKUs we union them using Proper Union a Custom VBA that allows for null values and removes duplicates.
    Set rngu = ProperUnion(rngx(1), rngx(2), rngx(3), rngx(4), rngx(5), rngx(6), rngx(7), rngx(8))
'Now that we have rngu which is the union of all flagged SKUs we want to intersect that with the SKUs that are in the chosen program.
    Set rngi = Intersect(rngA, rngu)
End Sub
```

Proper Union Code
From: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/BetterUnion.aspx

```
  Function ProperUnion(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) As Range
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' ProperUnion
    ' This provides Union functionality without duplicating
    ' cells when ranges overlap. Requires the Union2 function.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim ResR As Range
        Dim n As Long
        Dim r As Range

        If Not Ranges(LBound(Ranges)) Is Nothing Then 'xxxxxxxxxx
            Set ResR = Ranges(LBound(Ranges))
        End If
        For n = LBound(Ranges) + 1 To UBound(Ranges)
            If Not Ranges(n) Is Nothing Then
                For Each r In Ranges(n).Cells
                    If Application.Intersect(ResR, r) Is Nothing Then
                        Set ResR = Union2(ResR, r)
                    End If
                Next r
            End If
        Next n
        Set ProperUnion = ResR
    End Function
'Union2 is required for ProperUnion

Function Union2(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) As Range
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Union2
    ' A Union operation that accepts parameters that are Nothing.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim n As Long
        Dim RR As Range
        For n = LBound(Ranges) To UBound(Ranges)
            If IsObject(Ranges(n)) Then
                If Not Ranges(n) Is Nothing Then
                    If TypeOf Ranges(n) Is Excel.Range Then
                        If Not RR Is Nothing Then
                            Set RR = Application.Union(RR, Ranges(n))
                        Else
                            Set RR = Ranges(n)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next n
        Set Union2 = RR
    End Function
```

Comment: You should cite the source of `ProperUnion` to meet that sites requiremens - [Source: www.cpearson.com/Excel/BetterUnion.aspx Copyright 2013, Charles H. Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/BetterUnion.aspx)

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot that rule. I have it cited in the top module of my project, but forgot to link it here. Thank you very much for mentioning it. I'll add it to the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `rngx` to be a `Variant` array, but it should be declared as an array of `Range` objects.

So change the declaration to be:

```
Dim rngx(1 To 8) As Range
```

---

As currently written, the unassigned elements of `rngx` are being passed to `ProperUnion` with a type of `Variant/Empty`, which is why it is crashing.  By changing `rngx` to be `Range`, the parameters will be passed as `Variant/Range` with the unassigned elements being `Nothing`.

Comment: Hmmm.... Now I get the Error 5: Invalid Procedure on the line: `If Application.Intersect(ResR, r) Is Nothing Then`, but you did solve my initial question, so I'll definitely accept this as the answer when I can.

Comment: I don't think `ProperUnion` will work with `Nothing` as the first range, because `Application.Intersect` won't accept `Nothing` as one of its parameters.  I think it will need to be changed to use `If ResR Is Nothing Then` `Set ResR = r` `ElseIf Application.Intersect(ResR, r) Is Nothing Then` `Set ResR = Union2(ResR, r)` `End If`.